# Extract text from parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

How can I extract the text enclosed within the parenthesis from the following string:

```
string =  '{a=[], b=[abc, def], c=[ghi], d=[], e=[jkl], f=[mno, pqr, stu, vwx]}'
```

Expected Output is:

```
['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr','stu','vwx']
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, a community to help programmers where they are stuck, not a coding service where you will post your problems and we will provide the answers for you. Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex should help.

```
import re
string =  '{a=[], b=[abc, def], c=[ghi], d=[], e=[jkl], f=[mno, pqr, stu, vwx]}'
res = []
for i in re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", string):
    res.extend(i.replace(",", "").split())
print res
```

**Output:**

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx']
```

Comment: You have no reason to try to remove single quotes (`'`): no are present in original string.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using the newer `regex` module could be:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)([^][,]+)(?:,\s*)?
```

Broken down, this says:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)  # match either [ or at the end of the last match
([^][,]+)        # capture anything not [ or ] or ,
(?:,\s*)?        # followed by , and whitespaces, eventually
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/20D3gH/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import regex as re

string =  '{a=[], b=[abc, def], c=[ghi], d=[], e=[jkl], f=[mno, pqr, stu, vwx]}'
rx = re.compile(r'(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)([^][,]+)(?:,\s*)?')

output = rx.findall(string)
print(output)
# ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx']
```